# Why are my Performance Counter values reset when application terminates?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I have a web service that creates it's own single instance performance counters. When the pool shuts down (or recycled/restarted IIS) and perfmon is restarted, my int64 counters are all back to 0. Is there a way to create the category and/or counters so that they "survive" application shutdown?

Comment: Why do you want this intended behavior to be changed? When you are doing configuration changes it may reflect on your performance and therefor will not be shown in the performance counters if you not reset them. Explain this please.

Comment: It depends on what you monitor. I am talking about a Int64 counter that increments every time a certain event happens. And I do not want that counter to reset to 0 at all. Think of it as a history (log) and not real time monitoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to create the category and/or counters so that they "survive" application shutdown?

Yes, but only by implementing performance counters from scratch using the Win32 APIs, and for the component that PerfMon (or remoting of perf mon) uses to read the values for display this should be completely native code.

In practice it will be easier to provide your own persistence of values and set the initial values of the counters on start up (and this could then persist across things like machine restarts if desired).